# Align panel content to the top of panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have following example. What I would like is that the content of the panel is aligned to the top of the panel but it get's aligned in the center of the panel. I thought using GridBagLayout as manager and setting the anchor to NORTH should do the trick, obviously it does not.

Trying to clarify a few points:

- The save button should remain directly under the text area
- The textArea should have a maximum height so it does not keep growing as the frame keeps growing
- The save button should have a fixed width.

Also, if the frame gets too small height wise, the textArea suddenly resizes to one row only, I would like to have it reduce it's size gradually.

```
package layouttests;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LayoutTest extends JFrame
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LayoutTest()
    {
        setSize(50, 200);
        setLocation(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        JButton okButton = new JButton("Save");

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5,1);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        panel.add(scrollPane, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        panel.add(okButton, gbc);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        add(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new LayoutTest();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I think calling `gbc.weighty = 1.0;` should work for your first question. EDIT: Call it after adding the scrollpane if you want the scrollpane to stay the same height.

Comment: It does but there is a side effect: the textArea can become bigger than I want to (height I mean). How can I limit the maximum height of the text area? Is this something with setMaximumSize?

Comment: Change `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;` to `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;` (along with `weighty`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar approach, included the size limit

```
public LayoutTest()
{
    setSize(50, 200);
    setLocation(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JButton okButton = new JButton("Save");
    JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
    wrapper.add(okButton);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5,1);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setEditable(true);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
    scrollPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, 150));

    panel.add(scrollPane);
    panel.add(wrapper);
    panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    add(panel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: This looks good so far. Do you happen to know why the textArea now barely grows when increasing the height of the frame? Also, is it me or is the save button not centered anymore?

Comment: you can set the max height in here
scrollPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, 150));

Comment: To fix the centering of the button, juste create another panel, add the button to it, and add this panel instead of adding the button directly .

Comment: I went with this answer in the end because when using GridBoxLayout the textArea jumps from the intial size to a one row textarea when the window gets smaller which I didn't like.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, something like...

```
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
```

should would

Have a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details